# Trying to make ImageView full size in Dialog doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-dialog

I'm using **Fragments**, I would like to get full size image `mImageReport` when I tap on `ImageView` on my fragment. My second layout is test.xml (for Dialog).

I'm getting image from URL using `Picasso`

But the problem is my image doesn't appear on the new dialog (mImageReport). I don't know how to link the `imageView` from test.xml with the image I want in full screen in my fragment...

Here is my code.

Reports.java :

```
public class Reports extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reports, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

    final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    nagDialog.setCancelable(false);
    nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);
    Button btnClose = (Button)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnIvClose);
    ImageView ivPreview = (ImageView)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_preview_image);

    // Loading image from url in ImageView ... HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    Picasso.with(mImageReport.getContext()).load(mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages()).into(ivPreview);
    mImageReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nagDialog.show();
        }
    });

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                nagDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

test.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/iv_preview_image" />


    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:background="@drawable/fileclose"
            android:id="@+id/btnIvClose" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call this method from fragment onCreateView or according to your requirements...

```
private void showImage() {
    final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    nagDialog.setCancelable(false);
    nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);
    Button btnClose = (Button)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnIvClose);
    ImageView ivPreview = (ImageView)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_preview_image);

    // Loading image from url in ImageView ... HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages()).into(ivPreview);  

    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            nagDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    nagDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Mhhh, what did you change ? It's the line with Picasso, it makes my app crash

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jardelcompany.bundoransurfco/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco.TabsFragmentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at jardelcompany.bundoransurfco.Reports.onCreateView(Reports.java:131)

Comment: i guess you pass the context here
"    Picasso.with(mImageReport.getContext()).load(mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages()).into(ivPreview);   "

Check with getActivity()

Comment: Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages()).into(ivPreview); doesn't work :(  I don't know what to use for context... and I put this text at the end of OnCreate

Comment: is this worked for you?
and what you are asking about context?

Comment: I don't understand what I've to do... I added the showImage, but where I've to call it ? You didn't change something, and Picasso.with(getActivity()...) make my app crash...

Comment: in any click event (like button or what ever from onCreateView() of fragment) call showImage() and you are telling the app crashing at this line 
"     
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages()).into(ivPreview);   "
with-----context, 
load-----image url, and 
into-------imageview.